# Should user be logged out if they visit login page?

Tags: user-interface, authentication, user-controls, theory

I am developing an administration system and have come across a problem that I cannot figure out the best solution. When a user is logged into the system with valid credentials, the login link is removed from the page and all they can do is log out. However, if the user visits the login url, what should happen?

1. User gets redirected to previous page / dashboard etc
2. User gets logged out and must relogin via the login page.

There are benefits for both:

- **User redirect** - if the user accidentally visited the login page, then their workflow is not distrupted by having to re-login and getting redirected to a section in the admin system may be benefitial to them.
- **User logout** - The first port of call for most admin systems would be a generic /admin/login/ url or similar. If someone gained access to the users machine and tried one of these urls, auto logging them out would halt any malicious activity the person would have (if any)

From a usability perspective, I would be inclined to choose option 1. From a security perspective, option 2 makes more sense. Is there an obvious solution that I should choose or even one that I have missed? Or am I looking too deeply into it?

Comment: `From a usability perspective, I would be inclined to choose option 1` - I'd mostly agree with this, as option 2 isn't *really* that much more secure; while an auto-logout would secure the use case you give for #2, that's the *only* use case it secures for. Also, do you have a need for an explicit login page?

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would go with option one, It is what I would expect a website to do.

If you are concerned you could just do a check on the log in page to see if they are logged in and replace the log in box with something along the lines of 'Already logged in? Continue to the website or Click here to log out'.

Comment: I would prefer someone explain why they disagree, rather than down-vote and disappear.

Answer (score -1):

If the system uses a remote login, such as via a certificate on their local box, the user redirect method is very clean. Your users may have saved the Login URL as a favorite to return to your system often and this is a good way of handling it.

However, if your system "times out"/uses an expiring cookie to handle sessions, malicious behavior is much easier if the legitimate user walks away from the terminal after closing the window.

I would suggest that the correct solution is dependent on your unique system, but that the user experience option is the better choice.